# What commands can you send to LocationManager

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

What commands can you send to `locationManager.sendExtraCommands(provider, command, bundle);` I've been searching through the source code for the LocationManager class and i can't find other commands.

Answer (score 0):

It would be specific to the implementation of the provider.  So you shouldn't be looking in the LocationManager, you should be looking at the GPS and Network provider code.  I wouldn't trust any code that uses that to be portable across devices, it would be optimizing for a specific GPS chip.